# Redirecionamento de site http para https

Tags: apache, redirecionamento-de-url

Estou tentando publicar um site que está em um host interno da rede.
O objetivo é que quando acessamos da rede local http:// ipinterno, o site abra normalmente.
Também preciso publicar este site para acesso externo, para que seja acessado via https.
Temos apenas um IP Fixo. Fiz um NAT, para tudo que chegar no IPWAN na porta XXXXX, redirecione para a porta 443 do IPinterno.
Porem, o redirecionamento dentro do apache não esta correto.
Instalei e configurei o mod ssl para funcionar o https.

Segue o conteudo do meu arquivo ssl:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/site-ssl.conf

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Alias /owncloud "/var/www/html/owncloud/"
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 172.16.16.6
#Redirect / https://IPWAN:60004/owncloud
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName IPWAN
Redirect / https://IPWAN:60004/owncloud
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache/owncloud.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache/owncloud.key
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud
</VirtualHost>
```

Quando tento acessar, recebo este erro no Chrome: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Alguém poderia me dar uma dica ?

Comment: Você diz que redireciona de fora para a 443, mas aí a pessoa chega na 443 e você redireciona de novo pra 60004. Ai ele vai ficar em loop mesmo.

Comment: Olá Bacco. Obrigado pela ajuda. Você poderia me ajudar a consertar esta configuração ?  Com a configuração abaixo, eu chego na porta 443, diz que o certificado não é válido, ignoro e continuo. Porem a pagina não abre, porque surge o IP interno no endereço do navegador:

Comment: LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Alias /owncloud "/var/www/html/owncloud/"
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 172.16.16.6
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:60004>
ServerName 187.58.241.138
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName 187.58.241.138
#Redirect / https://187.58.241.138/owncloud
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache/owncloud.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache/owncloud.key
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @bacco, Consegui resolver a questão quando chego pela WAN na porta 443 ele redirecionava para o IP interno. No config.php do Owncloud adicionei o IP WAN em trusted_domains. É possível eu usar o ssl em uma porta que não seja a 443 ?

Comment: sim, basta que o endereço seja acessado com https:// - a vantagem de usar as portas convencionais (80 e 443) é que vc não precisa por o numero, o fato de ser http ou https seleciona cada uma. A unica coisa que muda quando vc usa nao padrão é ter que dizer o numero junto do protocolo. No seu caso, vc configura a 60004 só pra https. Se quiser usar os 2 protocolos, vai precisar de 2 portas de qq forma.

Comment: No apache quem diz se é https ou não é o SSLEngine on, a porta é irrelevante.

Comment: @Bacco, Obrigado pela ajuda. Ja me ajudou muito. Como faço para pontuar ou marcar como concluido o tópico ?

Comment: Se quiser, pode postar no campo das respostas, logo abaixo, sua solução, e marcar como aceita. Mas se achar que a situação ficou muito diferente do que foi perguntado, pode ser mais interessante deletar a pergunta só. Geralmente quando é coisa que bastante gente pode aproveitar a dúvida, o incentivo é deixar no site. Quando é coisa muito específica, que só serve pra um caso, pode ser melhor tirar. Veja como prefere.

Comment: Para utilizar o SSL sobre outra porta, no arquivo .conf do virtualhos, eu adicionei esta linha: Listen 60004 https.  Adicionei tambem: <VirtualHost _default_:60004> Agora o SSL roda sobre a porta 60004.